# Concurrent ajax requests in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, concurrency

I want to load several lists of numbers once the page has been displayed. These lists are placed at different elements of the page. The approach I've chosen so far is to create an a4j:jsFunction for each list of numbers that have to be loaded and use jQuery to fire these functions when the document is ready.

I'm using JSF 1.2, Facelets 1.1.14 and Richfaces 3.3.3. The relevant parts of the code are as follows.

XHTML:

```
<c:forEach items="#{testMB.list}" var="item" varStatus="status">
    <a4j:jsFunction name="loadNumbers_#{status.index}" action="#{testMB.loadNumbers}" reRender="numbers_#{status.index}">
        <a4j:actionparam name="index" value="#{status.index}" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</c:forEach>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        for (var i = 0; i < #{jstl:length(testMB.list)}; i++) {
            window['loadNumbers_' + i]();
        }
    });
    //]]>       
</script>
```

Managed Bean:

```
public void loadNumbers() {
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    int index = Integer.parseInt(params.get("index"));
    MyObject obj = list.get(index);
    obj.setNumbers(testBC.loadNumbers(obj));
}
```

The server receives all the ajax requests basically at the same time. It seems this concurrency has been causing some issues. For example, sometimes, the action method in the managed bean doesn't get called for some of the requests. Sometimes, even if the action method gets called for all requests, some of the lists are missing in the responses.

Using eventsQueue in the a4j:jsFunction solves the problem, as this creates a queue to prevent concurrent requests. Making the action method syncronized seems also to solve the problem. However, for a scenario I've been testing, the former and latter solutions takes about 55 and 30 seconds, respectivelly, while the first approach takes only about 12 seconds to load and show all the lists of numbers, when loaded correctly. As the computation of the lists of numbers may take quite a while, I'd like to take advantage of concurrent computation to show them in a timely fashion.

I'd appreciate any comments/suggestions on how to workaround this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using **a4j:poll** or **a4j:push**

My suggestion is.

use **t:datatable** or **t:panelGrid**  embedded with this grid inside **a4j:outputPanel** or  **t:panelGroup** give name as '**lists**'

use  **a4j:poll** or **a4j:push**  to refresh  give **rerender='lists'**

Hope this helps

Comment: Srikanth B, the lists are not going to change periodically. I only need to load them once. So a think a4j:poll and a4j:push are not really suitable here. Besides, I can't change the current layout of the page, so I'm not able to place the lists within a single grid. Having said that, I'll put some thought into how I can refactor the code to use a4j:pool or a4j:push anyways to see if the concurrency issue persists.

Comment: Srikanth B, thanks for your suggestion. I was able to refactor the page and use a4j:push to suit my purposes. When the managed bean is first called to load the data of the page, a thread is created for each list that needs to be computed. These threads are placed in a thread pool. I'm using the Executors API for that matter. As computation completes, aj4:push gets notified and the list's area is rerendered. That solution not only solves the synchronization problem, but it is even faster than previous ones. It takes only 7 seconds to compute and show all the lists in my tests.